# Datatables javascript sourced data without specifying column names

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to use an array of objects as an input to Datatables. Each object in the array I want to be a row in the table. Is there a way of inserting the data without specifying the column names?

```
var table = $('#data_table_test').DataTable( {
    "data": data,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "GENE_NAME" },
        { "data": "FDR"},
    ],
    dom: 'Bfrti',
    deferRender: true,
    scrollY: 420,
    scrollX: true,
    scroller: true,
    buttons: [
        'excel','csv'
    ],
    order: [],
} );
```

This works because I am specifying the column names, but I can't figure out a way to insert the data without using the column names.

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: @naveen Yea here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/jag_123/x4nw6mac/5/

Answer (score 1):

If the only issue is that you want to avoid naming the column, you could define the number of columns with just an empty definition

You could build the table definition in javascript based on your data and then pass it to the datatables initialization:

```
var tableDef = [ {}, {} ];

"columns": tableDef
```

I made a quick fiddle just to see if the idea works: https://jsfiddle.net/zyat1q2p/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of columns won't be the same for every table

Comment: What if you built a javascript variable to become your columns definition?

Comment: yea I think I might have to go that route.